# How do i make my text wrap in a <div> with a large border radius

Tags: html, css

in the following code

```
<html>
<body>
<div style="height:400px; width:400px;  -moz-border-radius:100px; -webkit-border-radius:100px; border:3px solid #500;     background-color:#a00; overflow:hidden;">
Why is this getting cut at the beginning???
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why isn't the browser wrapping the text around the rounded corners. 
In webkit browsers(i tested both chrome and safari) the overflow hidden cuts the text outside the border. Firefox just renders text outside the border. I also tried this without overflow:hidden; but again the text just rendered outside the border.

Comment: I understand that I can use padding but I'm trying to find out if it will wrap itself around the border that way the width of the text can expand as the border around it expands. Consider trying to fill a circle completely with text

Answer (score 4):

Use padding to adjust your content

```
padding-left:20px;
padding-top:50px;
```

Hence it looks like...

```
<div style="height:400px; width:400px;  -moz-border-radius:100px; -webkit-border-radius:100px; border:3px solid #500;     background-color:#a00; overflow:hidden;padding-left:20px;padding-top:50px;">
```

Answer (score 1):

if your borders radius is 100px/
you should use that/

```
div.blabla{padding:36px;}
```

this is a good padding ratio for divs with border-radius 36%/

Comment: I am curious to know why that ratio is good? I like understanding different rules for design.

Comment: 36% is minimum ofcourse/
its for border-radius/
because, border-radius can cut paragraphs inside of div/

Comment: Off topic, but - why all of the "/"?